# Pass a primitive data type in request body in the Angular HTTP PUT

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot, angular-httpclient, http-put

I have a service method and I need to pass a UUID through a String property to the service using an HTTP PUT request through request payload (i.e., body).

The signature of the Java Spring Boot API controller method is

```
@PutMapping("group/{groupId}/updateFile")
    public String deleteAgencyFile(@PathVariable("groupId") UUID reportId,@RequestBody UUID fileId) {

    // Internal Operations - TODO

    return 'SUCCESS';
}
```

Angular HTTP PUT code:

```
updateGroupFile() {
    const groupId: string = 'b9ddab47-56a2-11e9-8882-484d7ee28bcd';
    const fileId: string = 'c0822353-56a2-11e9-8882-484d7ee28bcd';

    const filePath = `http://localhost:3000/api/group/${groupId}/updateFile`

    return this.http.put<SimpleResponse>(filePath, fileId);
}
```

Once I'm subscribing to the Angular method I'm getting the error:

```
{
   "timestamp":"2019-04-04T06:30:32.098+0000",
   "status":400,
   "error":"Bad Request",
   "message":"JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'c0822353': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'c0822353': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 10]",
   "path":"/api/group/b9ddab47-56a2-11e9-8882-484d7ee28bcd/updateFile"
}
```

I tried the same in POSTMAN, it's working but in the Angular application it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error cause the second parameter of `put()` expects a valid JSON. Valid code would be

```
updateGroupFile() {
    const groupId: string = 'b9ddab47-56a2-11e9-8882-484d7ee28bcd';
    const fileId: string = 'c0822353-56a2-11e9-8882-484d7ee28bcd';

    const filePath = `http://localhost:3000/api/group/${groupId}/updateFile`

    return this.http.put<SimpleResponse>(filePath, {fileId});
}
```

or if you want a specific param name then

```
return this.http.put<SimpleResponse>(filePath, {'id': fileId});
return this.http.put<SimpleResponse>(filePath, {'uuid': fileId});
```

and so on ... It depends on your UUID implementation in your code as well

Comment: I tried this, if I passed in this way it goes like `{ "fileId": "c0822353-56a2-11e9-8882-484d7ee28bcd" }` - It won't accept.

Comment: It won't accept? Are you still getting the error? or it won't accept in the backend?

Comment: Both the objects are different, The API will accept the GUID not a object.